# Bayesian variant of Ljung-Box test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, garch

I am using Bayesian MCMC estimation methods for GARCH models and I want to check, if model residuals are uncorrelated. In classical frequentist approach, one would use standard Ljung-Box test to check this. But with MCMC estimation, I have 10,000 volatility samples (so 10,000 residuals) for each observation. So is there any sufficient method how to perform some correlation test in Bayesian sense?

Comment: The Bayesian approach is usually not to test but _to model_. That is, one would include an AR coefficient or [some more general term](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/498872) in the likelihood and see if it improves the model.